# C# Web Forms : Update Set doesn't update Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using ASP .NET Web Forms . I have 8 Textboxes in which the user can input data for a specific row on the SQL and make changes on the database accordingly for a car, with make, model, year, engine, the rate, availability and location.

I am using the Update Set SQL query as seen on the  code line "string query" but it doesn't do anything to the database.

I have established a connection on the SQL Server with Visual Studio 2022

```
string a = TextBox1.Text;
            string b = TextBox2.Text;
            string c = TextBox3.Text;
            string d = TextBox4.Text;
            string ee = TextBox5.Text;
            string f = TextBox6.Text;
            string g = TextBox7.Text;
            string h = TextBox8.Text;


            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TLESConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string query = "UPDATE MyCar SET Make = @Make, Model = @Model, Year = @Year ,Engine = @Engine , Rate = @Rate ,Availability = @Availability , Location = @Location";

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Make", a);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", b);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", c);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Engine", d);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rate", ee);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Availability", f);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", g);
            conn.Close();
```

What is your suggestion as to why it is not updating the Row ?

Comment: Update only update if the row already exists.   If row doesn't exist use Insert.  Where is your ExcuteNonQuery() statement?  You need to test the value returned which is number of rows changed.  If no row is changed with Update than repeat with insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing a few aspects. You are defining the query, which is correct, and you set the parameters and values correctly. You never execute the query, however, and after setting the variables, you close the connection.

I copied your code, made these changes, and it worked for me. Give it a try.

```cs
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TLESConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string query = "UPDATE MyCar SET Make = @Make, Model = @Model, Year = @Year ,Engine = @Engine , Rate = @Rate ,Availability = @Availability , Location = @Location";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Make", a);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", b);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", c);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Engine", d);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rate", ee);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Availability", f);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", g);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

As you can see, after inputting all of the variables, I am executing the query, thus making it work. You were just missing:

```cs
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Well done so far.

Answer (score 0):

**Dont you need to add a condition as to where you want to update the values?**

[Example from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

**Also have you checked if the connection string and the query are both correct?**
You can use the Debug for that, check the string value / content for both the connection and the query

**On top of that, I noticed that you opened a connection and created a Command, but you didnt run the command, you close the connection, are you running the command?**

You could do that with:

```
try
    {
         Com.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
          return;
      }
```

EDIT: You only need to use the 'Where' clause if you want to update a specific value rather than the entire table, **If you omit the 'WHERE' clause, ALL records will be updated**